# What kind of distribution is this (PDF bounded within interval)?

Tags: probability-distributions

Please excuse my naïvety in this matter, but what kind of distribution is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1448935/101417), where the max/min is bounded by a definite interval (in this case, $[0,3]$ )? I can see the (elegant) accepted answer is a triple intergal, but is it possible to define the relevant distribution plot, and integrate once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X, Y, Z$ are i.i.d. with uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$,
then $T = X+Y+Z$ has pdf

$$ f(t) = \cases{ {t}^{2}/2&$0 \le t\le 1$\cr -3/2-{t}^{2}+3\,t&$1 \le t\le 2$\cr 9/2-3\,t+{t}^{2}/2&$2 \le t\leq 3$\cr 0& otherwise\cr}$$

Comment: must it be defined piecewise?

Comment: Essentially yes (though you could use Heaviside functions etc to get the same effect).  The second derivative of the pdf is $+1$ on the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$, but $-2$ on $(1,2)$.

Comment: how did you find this? How would I go about finding the pdf for any $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ that are i.i.d. with uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]?$ Where should I look for literature on the subject?

Comment: Actually, I used Maple.  But you can do it yourself.  If $f_n$ is the pdf for $X_1 + \ldots + X_n$, then $$f_{n+1}(x) = \int_{0}^1 f_n(x-t)\; dt$$
Do it on each interval $[j,j+1)$ separately.

Comment: thanks - will give it a go - any idea how to set up in _Mathematica_?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Mathematica.

Comment: don't worry, thanks for the tip anyway - will give it a go manually :)

Comment: For reference: the PDF presented here can be seen as a suitably scaled quadratic B-spline basis function.